# Database Chunking and pagination for large data

Tags: sql, oracle

We need to store entities in groups, each groups can have around 10 million entities, we need to read all the entities belonging to a particular group since each query will need to fetch millions of entities this is not allowed, the sample table looks like this

| ID | GROUP_ID | DATA | IS_ACTIVE | ....... | TIME_CREATED | TIME_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |  | 1 | ....... | 1212 | 1212 |
| 2 | 101 |  | 1 | ....... | 1212 | 1212 |
| ..... | ... | ...... | . | ....... | .... | .... |
| 7897897 | 101 |  | 1 | ....... | 1616 | 1616 |

Can anyone please suggest some options on how to chunk the records so that each query will fetch around 1k records and need not to access all the records?

We thought of this query for chunking with 1000 records in each query

```
select
    trunc(rn/1000) chunk_id,
    group_id,
    min(id) as startKey,
    max(id) as endKey,
    count(1) as chunk_count
from
    (
        select
            group_id, id, rownum as rn
        from
            (
                select group_id, id from entity_data where group_id = '101' order by id
            )
    )
group by trunc(rn/1000), group_id order by 1
```

But the above query was rejected as for each query we still need to access all the records and compute the chunks and there are memory constraints in oracle.

Edit 1: The database we use is shared among different users. The amount of data in it keeps growing. When we run certain searches, we have to pick out a large number of records, like 5 to 10 million, from a total of about 100 million entries. Each time we do this search, we end up pulling in a lot of data, around 3 to 5 gigabytes. The thing is, doing this can slow down the database and affect other people using it. So, we need to be careful about how we fetch data to make sure it doesn't cause issues for everyone else.

Comment: Why isn't it allowed to fetch millions of rows? The # of rows fetched has no memory constraints on the database. Millions of rows is nothing in the world of Oracle. There is likely no need for you to paginate at all.

Comment: The database that we are using is a shared database, the data will keep on increasing and we'll have to select 5-10 M of records from around 100 M entities based on some conditions, for each query we'll need to fetch around 3-5 gb of data this will affect other users on the database.

Comment: No, I don't think it will. 5 million and 5GB are not very large numbers. Fetching rows doesn't cost anything but network bandwidth. What matters more is how much work the database may need to do to read the segment and perform any joins and sorts your query may require. If you hint for excessive degrees of parallelism and the DBA hasn't put proper limits in place and your database server is tiny, yes, you can cause impairment. But this is precisely the reason *not* to paginate, as pagination requires unnecessarily repeating all the above work over and over again.

Comment: Get your DBA to spell out *technically* in Oracle terms DBAs understand what their concern is.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider:

- Create an index on `group_id` and `id` so that you only need to read from the index and not the table.
- Create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with the output from your query so that your query only has to run once (or once after you modify the table) and then you can get the output you want from the view instead of the table.

You could also consider using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` if you want the start and end of consecutive sequences of ids:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT group_id, id FROM entity_data WHERE group_id = 101)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY group_id
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES
    FIRST(id) AS startkey,
    LAST(id) AS endkey,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS chunk,
    COUNT(*) AS chunk_count
  PATTERN (sequential_id* last_id)
  DEFINE sequential_id AS id + 1 = NEXT(id) 
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pjMBQZ6U)

Then you don't need to limit the chunks to 1000 and can have whatever size you need and know that within a chunk all the ids are sequential (rather than not knowing if there are gaps).

Apply some or all of the suggestions as best fits your problem.